# Hiding ios keyboard in Cordova. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am using cordova 3.4.0 and I would like to hide the keyboard once the ajax call did the job on search. I would like to avoid users to press "done" to hide de keyboard and see the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute the ajax call, try this :

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

With this you lose focus on the current element and the keyboard disappear.

Comment: Yes, great! Thank you. It works perfectly and is more simple than I expect. I really was not thinking about the keyboard binded on the input focus.